# Match vertical slash

Tags: c#, regex

How can I match vertical slash `|` in regular expression

I've trying to match content like this `"1|2|3|4|"` with this regex expression  
"`(<group1>.*?)|.*?|.*?|(<group2>.*?)|`

I'd like to get in first group value `1` and in second `4` This regular expression is not working

Comment: I've just edited question , i would like to match vetical slash symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is close, just remove the question marks. Asterisks match 0 or more so there's not need for question marks.

The \ escapes |. You're missing a couple back slashes. It should be something like:

```
(<group1>.*)\|.*\|.*\|(<group2>.*)\|
```

And you'll need to add the @ sign in front of the string declaration for C# to take the literal text.

```
@"backslash\all day"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Romoku's answer, you can do one of the other two if you do not want to use `Regex.Escape`

```
// double backslash "\\" to escape the \ in c# so it gets passed to regex
"(<group1>.*?)\\|.*?|.*?|(<group2>.*?)|"

// use the @ sign to indicate to c# to take text verbatim
@"(<group1>.*?)\|.*?|.*?|(<group2>.*?)|"
```